# Change the color of one button in gnome shell

Tags: css

I have changed the color of all the buttons and other items in a gnome shell theme by editing the css except one. Its blue while all the others are lavender.
[different color button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gOrt.jpg) I have went over the css file a dozen times and cant find the blue color. I cant seem to find the answer in a search. While I can edit css I am not really good at it. Here is a [link to the css file](https://spins.tuxfamily.org/gnome-shell.css). Thanks in advance if someone can point out what I have missed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please put code direct into your question rather than on an external site which may disappear, making your question useless for future readers.

Comment: I only linked to the css file because I am not sure what code in the file controls the color of the button. The file is 2175 lines of code and didnt appear to me to be a good idea to post that much in a comment. The file is on my site, and I wont remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I kept at it and found the problem. It only took a few hours of banging my head into a wall. The .quick-menu-toggle .quick-toggle-arrow was missing a background-color. The solution was to add it.

```
.quick-menu-toggle .quick-toggle-arrow {
  background-color: #8F66F2;
  padding: 6px 10.5px; }
```